# Access a model through a link filterd model

Tags: python, django

I have three models Person, User and Profile. Profile links a person to a user like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    person = models.OneToOneField(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

In my person detail view I want to get the username through the person selected.

```
class PersonDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'people/person_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PersonDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        profile = Profile.objects.filter(person_id=Person.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']))

        # this line is the problem I guess
        user = User.objects.get(pk=profile.user.user_id)

        context['user_person'] = user
        return context
```

With this code I get the error

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'

Maybe it is a silly question but I'm lost on this.
How do I get the user from The profile filtered from a person?

Thanks in advance, I hope I made mydelf clear enough.

**EDIT**

I got everything workin with Robert Townley answers, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The line that says:

```
profile = Profile.objects.filter(person_id=Person.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']))
```

should instead grab the Profile from the queryset:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(person_id=Person.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']))
```

If you do "filter()" you'll receive a queryset. If you do "get()" you'll receive the only object matching that queryset. You can also do:

```
profile_queryset = Profile.objects.filter(person_id=Person.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']))
profile = profile_queryset.first()
```

Note: Only do this if you're sure that the Profile object exists, or you'll get a DoesNotExist error.

Comment: Beat me to it. Always remember that `.filter()` returns the `QuerySet` array and not an actual object, even if there is only 1 returned object, it's still a `QuerySet`

Comment: I get another error applying this answer (1054, "Unknown column 'edu_profile.id' in 'field list'") maybe I'm wrong on another part of the code, I guess this answer is not helpul.

Comment: Have you run ./manage.py makemigrations and ./manage.py migrate since making your latest model changes? Do either of those commands create/apply any new migrations?

Comment: Thanks! the table profile did't have an id... I don't know why on tprevious migrations didn't add it. Still I get some errors i will keep tryin and post an answer.

Comment: @RobertTownley your code works but now I have the problem that profile model won't generate id auto increment on save (if I add the record directly on the database everything works). I'm using aview that saves profile and user at the same time, maybe I should post another question.

Comment: Yeah another question would be useful for being able to see the view, error message, and how it's trying to save the model. Only thing I'd say is to make sure that the User has been saved to the database by the time the Profile is trying to access it. That's been an issue of mine in the past, but I couldn't tell you much more without seeing the view and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you are creating a relation table to connect a Person with a User.

You do not have to create relation tables in django.

Instead you should add a foreignkey
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related

Comment: I guess you mean adding a foreign key in person model to user model, but I don't want every person to have a user.

Comment: @guillermochamorro You can have the foreignkey to be optional with setting the _null_ value for the field. You can also add the foreignkey to user model instead. You may not have a User for all Person, but you might have a Person for each User.

Comment: but If I want to use person as a module on other project without user I will have a problem... or at least maybe it's not a good practice?

Comment: You can of course use both Person and User as foreignkey in another model also.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, You can use simple soulution for your logic,

```
class PersonDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'people/person_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PersonDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_person'] = self.request.user
        # Just only one action
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need this:

```
class PersonDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'people/person_detail.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    user = self.object.profile.user if hasattr(self.object, 'profile') else None
    return super(PersonDetailView, self).get_context_data(user_person=user, **kwargs)
```